# couldn't resolve parse.api.com , Error code - 6 with parse-php-sdk

Tags: php, parse-platform, php-parse-error

## couldn't resolve parse.api.com

I am unable to even login in my website which is parse-php-sdk based.I got couldn't resolve parse.api.com error with Error code - 6, do i have to change something in my code ?I really want some permanent solution with this, this problem occurs only with my remote host and not my localhost. What is the exact issue and how can i get rid of this issue permanently. Please help. It automatically resolves afterwards but I need a permanent solution for this.

Comment: make sure you have used your API keys well. and compile it step by step in restClient Class. you need to set URL and data well to call any APIs.

Comment: Yup they r correct, m still not able to reciprocate the cause